# Do questions concerning topics that are not exclusively SFF related, but are found in SFF, on or off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

This is in relation to the following question:

[Historical basis for the character of the fool](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2104/historical-basis-for-the-character-of-the-fool)

While this is not an element that is exclusive to SFF, it certainly is not an uncommon element in medieval-themed fantasy novels. Would this be considered off topic?  I'm on the fence about it...initially I felt that is *was* on topic, since it is an element found in fantasy novels, but I can see the other rationale as well.  Thoughts?

Comment: Then why not make it specific? But either way, this question is far too general. A fool is hardly a SF&F specific character

Comment: This is essentially what I was asking here: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/377/are-questions-that-would-strongly-benefit-from-additional-domain-knowledge-accept which was closed as a dupe of http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266/sci-fi-technology-on-topic where there were 6 votes for asking here, 5 votes for asking elsewhere. It's also discussed in http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-questions-are-off-topic but only in a very unclear way.

Answer (score 1):

I felt like the question was only tangentially related to Sci-Fi or Fantasy, and therefore I closed it.

Answer (score 1):

Are questions that try to put SFF in a larger literary context considered off topic if the answer to those questions are not necessarily SFF related?  I am of the opinion that if the answer serves to improve understanding of the works involved then it should be considered on topic.